# Changing Random.Range to pick enemy 1, then enemy 2 after a delay?

Tags: c#

Using the code below how would I code it so instead of it randomly spawning an enemy from the array, it spawns enemy1, then enemy 2 after say 10 second delay, but still uses the random spawn delays and die time?

Might be simple but i just cant see it..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] enemies;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("SpawnHandler");
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawnHandler()
    {
        float spawnDelay;
        int thisEnemy = 0;
        GameObject cachedEnemy;
        float dieTime;

        while (thisEnemy < 2)
        {
            spawnDelay = Random.Range(3f,6f); //random time, from 1-3
            dieTime = Random.Range(3f,3f);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnDelay); //wait that time
            cachedEnemy = (GameObject)Instantiate(enemies[thisEnemy],
                  transform.position, transform.rotation);//spawn enemy, cache him
            StartCoroutine(Kill(dieTime, cachedEnemy));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Kill(float wait, GameObject enemy)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
        Destroy(enemy);
    }
}
```

to reiterate what I need to accomplish: -> randoms spawn delay -> spawns enemy 1 -> delay (say 10 seconds) -> spawns enemy 2 -> loop;

Hope thats clear and any help is greatly appreciated, 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the condition of your `while` loop:

```
private IEnumerator SpawnHandler(){
    float spawnDelay;
    int thisEnemy = 0;
    GameObject cachedEnemy;
    float dieTime;

    while (thisEnemy < 2)
    {
        spawnDelay = Random.Range(3f,6f); //random time, from 1-3
        dieTime = Random.Range(3f,3f);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnDelay); //wait that time

        cachedEnemy = (GameObject)Instantiate(enemies[thisEnemy],       transform.position, transform.rotation);//spawn enemy, cache him

        StartCoroutine(Kill(dieTime, cachedEnemy));
        thisEnemy++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to keep the condition of the `while` loop as `true`, just do 
`thisEnemy = thisEnemy == 0 ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: What you done was spot on to the question i cannot fault you there. However it was meant to loop not die; so they constantly come after the random times. Also the enemyTwo should die after 1 second not the same dieTime as enemy one of 3f. That's where it got tricky for me, again thank you for the answer i was wrong on my part, ive included all the code in the questions and double checked the wording. Its tricky!

Comment: See my first comment.